# How do I delete a board in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is it possible to delete a board in Trello? I see how to pin or unpin it, or add it to an organization. Best I can come up with is remove everyone else from it and set it to member visibility. Guess I could create a dummy user to assign deleted boards too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can *close* a board from the board's menu: click on the icon next to the board's name, then select **Close Board**.

You can *re-open* a board from the Boards menu (this is a different menu): click on **Boards** near the upper right corner of the page, then select **View Closed Boards**.

Comment: Hadn't even discovered that menu yet. Wasn't very obvious I guess.

Comment: The option to CLOSE a board is not evident. Can you share a screenshot of how this is done because so far, I have not seen any option to close a board.

Comment: FYI, this does not seem to apply to Organization Boards. See also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28737/how-to-close-archive-an-organization-board

Answer (score 4):

There's a workaround that I'm using. If you want to get rid of a board, even if you're the admin, you can follow these steps:

1. Remove any people from the board (It's annoying for other people having a dead board)
2. If you have any sensitive information. Delete the cards
3. So you're the admin, you cannot leave the board, just close it. But..
4. Add Trello user as a new member, and give him admin permission.
5. Now you can leave and get rid the board

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the difference in location between the board's menu and the Boards menu:

- The board's menu is found while looking at the board you want to close, to the left of the name of the board, it opens by clicking on the icon similar to the trello icon, but in grey. This is where you can close a board.
- The Boards menu is located in the upper right corner.