# How to close/archive an organization board?

Tags: trello

[From Trello Guide](https://trello.com/guide):

> Close a board by selecting "Close Board" from the board menu (the 
>   icon by the board title).

I have a board that belongs to an organization (I photoshopped the image below to remove the org name, but believe me, it does). Can I archive it? How?

[image]

[See also How do I delete a board in Trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19672/how-do-i-delete-a-board-in-trello)

Comment: Are you the owner of the board?

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant - hmm, I forgot to check this ... I guess I am not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're able to close the board if you are the board owner.

Comment: Just for completion: I was not the owner of the welcome board, so I could not close it. But I could leave it ... and then it was gone.